# Does print() cost CPU cycles?

Tags: cpu

Does `eosio::print` cost CPU cycles to execute on the BPs?
On my node I have an option to print. Assuming it is disabled for the BPs (`print` defined to `return;` or similar), does evaluating the arguments cost CPU cycles, e.g.

```
print("Hi", expensiveFunction());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print()` appears to cost CPU cycles and `expensiveFunction()` is evaluated.
I tried with the following. As there is no sleep I just looped (the expensive function takes about 50 ms > 30 ms allowed on the test node).
This results in `Error 3080006: Transaction took too long`

```
string expensiveFunction()
{
  int volatile i = 0;
  for(; i<600000;)
    {
      i++;
    }
  return to_string(i);
}

ACTION performance::testprint()
{
  print("start");
  print("hi", expensiveFunction());
  print("stop");
}
```

Comment: We decided to avoid this by putting a macro around the print commands like `D(print(...);)`. The macro looks like this `#define DEBUG 0` `#if DEBUG` `#define D(x) x` `#else` `#define D(x)` `#endif`